# Android webview shows blank screen after sharing the content on facebook wall ? I am using javascript sdk to share the Post

Tags: facebook-graph-api, webview, android-webview, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am using the javascript sdk to share content on a Facebook wall:

```
 FB.ui({
          method:'share',
          display: 'touch',
          href: 'www.adarshkr.com',
          redirect_uri:'www.adarshkr.com'
        }, 
        function(response) {
          if (response && !response.error) 
          {
            alert("shared");
            window.reload();
            console.log(response)
          }
          else
          {
            FB.init();
          }
        });
```

Upon sharing the content its not taking to URL which is specified in redirect_uri. In Android webview, upon sharing the content i am getting the blank screen.. I am not getting response from the facbook.